# Argument of type "unsigned long *" is incompatible with parameter of type "HCRYPTHASH *"

Tags: c++, md5, unsigned, wincrypt

I'm using Visual Studios 2012 on Windows 8.1, on a 64 bit machine. I'm having trouble compiling the following code for c++, getting the above error:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
void MD5Init(MD5Context *ctx)
{
    CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &ctx->hHash);
}
```

However, this seems to be the way this is called ([here is one which has the same call and gives me the same error](https://github.com/sakbhav/PassWd_Mgr/blob/master/passcrypt.cpp)). VS suggests a couple of possible fixes, which I'll try, but does anyone know why this behaviour is happening and how to avoid it?

The suggested fixes are:

> error C2664: 'CryptCreateHash' : cannot convert parameter 5 from
>   'unsigned long *' to 'HCRYPTHASH *' Types pointed to are unrelated;
>
> conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style
>   cast

Thanks,

Aodhán

Edit: It doesn't happen for 32 bit compilation, so I guess that's what the examples I've read were done in. I'll update whether the suggested fixes worked for 64 bit compilation.

Comment: _conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast_ Doesn't this help you?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try out those and see if they work - but none of the examples I've seen used those so I'm asking the question why it should be the case that it happens here.

Comment: Your MD5Context.hHash member isn't big enough in 64-bit mode.  The simple workaround is to declare it as  HCRYPTHASH instead of unsigned long.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad I know that now.